# Android - App crashes

Tags: android, crash, oncreate, cyanogenmod

I need your help... I have an app, it has a splash screen in the onCreate(). Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGHT = 3000;
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        super.setTheme(R.style.Fullscreen);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /* New Handler to start the Menu-Activity 
         * and close this Splash-Screen after some seconds.*/
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,List.class);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                MainActivity.this.finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGHT);
    }
```

I uninstalled OS X from my Macbook air, Insalled Ubuntu and imported the project. Now it just crashes... Can you help me? If need more details ask please!

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted the imported utilities and reimported them... now working fine.